# Derivation of the formula for $m$ compounding periods per year: $(1+\frac{i}{m})^{mt}$

Tags: returns

A dollar return with interest $i$ invested for $T$ years with compounding interest frequency of $m$ times each year is:

$$1*(1+\frac{i}{m})^{mt}.$$

*My Question*

1. Why do we divide $i$ by $m$? Is this because $i$ represents annual interest rate, but it is compounded $m$ times a year, so we need to compute the effective interest rate at each compounding periods?
2. How do we analytically derive this formula?

Comment: @AlexC Great. Can you make your response to an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about interest rate conventions and terminology. When people say "i percent a year compounded m times a year" it means the following: $i$ is called the *quoted rate*, which is not directly used in the calculation. Instead the first step is to calculate $\frac{i}{m}$  which is called the *periodic rate* and then apply this rate to every period. If there are t years, there are $mt$ periods and therefore the formula above follows.

Comment: It is also a natural way to express the relationship, as $lim_{m\to\infty}(1+\frac{i}{m})^{mt}=e^{it}$. (It converges to the continuous compounding expression in the limit.)